# z-index causing sliding within div

Tags: css, html, z-index

FOr some reason, when I have z-index:0 for an image, the div shows correctly, but can slide up/down within the parent div.  However, if I have z-index:-100 the image disappears, and no longer slides.

Is there any way to have z-index:0 without the image moving around within the parent div?  I want the image to be locked into position.  Thank you!

frame_th img is the div I want locked in place.

```
.frame_th {
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.frame_th img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    margin: 30px 0 0px 26px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well please.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `.frame_th` a `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`, and `.frame_th img` a `z-index: 0`. This should keep the image positioned correctly in the parent div with no sliding.

Comment: note that you'll need to explicitly define a `height` for `.frame_th`, as the absolutely-positioned image within won't influence the parent's height automatically.